# Checking for NULLs/BLANKs in Dynamic Content

Tags: marketing-cloud

I need to create an email with Dynamic Content.. In the same I have various rules.
For e.g. - FirstName is NULL and LastName is NOT NULL

My problem is how do I check for NULL and NOT NULL in these rules

I tried FirstName = NULL ; FirstName = "" ; FirstName = ''

None is working .. Please advise

Comment: Not sure where you are doing this but you are using the '=' assignment operator and not the '==' comparison operator. Is this in apex? Can you be a bit more specific

Comment: Hi Eric, this is exacttarget (Marketing Cloud) ... using while creating rules of the dynamic content ..
on the UI, it shows like FirstName IS EQUAL TO ""

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the [AttributeValue()](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#attributevalue) function, which will return an empty string if the variable is not defined.  Then you can use the [empty()](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#example) function to check it:

```
%%[

var @firstName, @lastName
set @firstName = AttributeValue("FirstName")
set @lastName= AttributeValue("lastName")

if empty(@firstName) then
  outputline(concat("<br>first name is empty"))
else
  outputline(concat("<br>first name has a value: ", @firstName))
endif

]%%
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are creating via the Dynamic Content Area block in the UI, you should be able to select "is empty" or "is not empty" from the drop down in the filters for creating the rule.  See below:

[image]

If you are using AMPScript, you will need to use the [EMPTY()](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#example) and NOT EMPTY() functions in your IF THEN statement. Please make sure to follow the [conditions syntax and If statement syntax](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/#section_14).

Comment: Surprisingly, I don't see these 'empty', 'not empty' options .. Do I need to contact Salesforce? Is it something configurable?

Comment: Yes, make sure they enabled drag and drop segmentation on your account.

Comment: I reached out to Salesforce. They said Drag & Drop is a beta feature and is not available at present. They are also going to update their documentation. The above 2 options are not available presently

Comment: That is weird, this was originally released back in 2013 prior to Salesforce even buying them - http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/release_notes/november_2013_release/#Email

Comment: also, that screen shot came from my account that has those options...

Comment: I too am curious about that screenshot. The drag and drop can be used for filtering data extensions and whatnot, but for dynamic content I am seeing the same thing as Maneesh. It would seem that you are in a beta of some sort, in which case I'm jealous :P

Comment: Hmm, I will look into this on my end.  If so, I believe it will be available to all in next update as announced in Connections2016

Answer (score 0):

Even I was stuck with same issue.

Quick fix:

When creating the dynamic content rule: 
1. Select the desired attribute 
2. Set the operator to "exists in" 
3. Enter a space followed by a comma (,) in the value field  (do not include parenthesis)

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000ZkshQAC